# Unable to run setDefaultHostnameVerifier

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Basically I'm trying to execute the following code within an lotus notes java agent in a local database to force ignore the host name mismatch for the SSL certificate.

```
HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                        System.out.println("Warning: URL Host: " + urlHostName + " vs. "
                                + session.getPeerHost());
                        return true;
                    }
                };
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

However, I'm encountering an error that says that the access to the particular method is denied

> java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied
>   (javax.net.ssl.SSLPermission setHostnameVerifier)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:100)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:174)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
>     at
>   COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.superDotCheckPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1449)
>     at
>   COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1617)
>     at
>   COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1464)
>     at
>   javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection.java:40)
>     at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:45)   at
>   lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)   at
>   lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

I have tried the following code inside the java.policy file but the error remains the same

> permission javax.net.ssl.SSLPermission “setHostnameVerifier”;

I tried the same code in eclipse IDE and ran it and worked well.

Comment: In some cases, putting the code in an external jar file seems to do the trick. Have you seen this article? http://lekkimworld.com/2013/06/20/java_in_notes_domino_explained_on_java_security_and_how_it_relates_to_notes_domino.html

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the article. External jar file and elevated permission for the function.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. An upvote and/or accept would be appreciated! :-)

Comment: It was a comment so I only upvoted it... If you could put it in the 'answer your question', I will upvote and accept it as an answer right away.

Comment: You're right! I had debated whether or not to make it an answer, but had decided not to since these kinds of permission issues can be so mysterious. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, putting the code in an external jar file seems to do the trick. Have you seen this [article](http://lekkimworld.com/2013/06/20/java_in_notes_domino_explained_on_java_security_and_how_it_relates_to_notes_domino.html)? It goes into a lot of detail about solving problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was proguard obfuscating classes in org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider. What I did was add the following to my proguard.conf file:

`-keep class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.** { *; }`